# Show full line of a CSV file C++

Tags: c++, csv, tree

I am making a program that reads a .CSV file and loads it into binary search trees to sort its content, since I managed to load the .CSV and implement the tree however the content of the file is:

1, Peter, 230151515
5, Merrick, 25551561
7, Lucky, 4301616199
2, luis, 2589191919
16, Alfredo, 25891919
8, Linda, 129616919

I am using the first data of each row as a key and with the code that I carry, it orders it correctly, however I want it to show the rest of the row, not just the key, someone could tell me how I could do that, to show all the data of each key ordered.

output:
1
2
5
7
8
16

What I want to print would be something like:

1 Peter 230151515
2 Luis 2589191919
5 Merrick 25551561
7 Lucky 4301616199
8 Linda 129616919
16 Alfredo 25891919

### Someone to help me correct my mistake please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int key;
    string name;
    int num;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

vector<node> persons;


struct node *newNode(int item)
{
    struct node *temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        //cout<<"\t";

        inorder(root->left);
        printf("\t%d\n", root->key);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}

struct node * minValueNode(struct node* node)
{
    struct node* current = node;

    /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
    while (current && current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}




int main()
{
    struct node *root = NULL;
    ifstream fin("data.txt");
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "File not open\n";
        return 1;
    }



    string line;
    const char delim = ',';


    while (getline(fin, line))
    {
        istringstream ss(line);
        node person;
        ss >> person.key; ss.ignore(10, delim);
        getline(ss, person.name,delim);
        ss >> person.num;
        if (ss)
            persons.push_back(person);
    }


   for (unsigned int i=0; i< persons.size(); i++)
   {
         cout << setw(5)  << persons[i].key<< setw(20) << persons[i].name<< setw(15)  << persons[i].num << '\n';

             root = insert(root, persons[i].key);
            insert(root, persons[i].key);


   }


    cout << "\n\nInorder:\n";
//    cout<<node.name;

    inorder(root);

    /*/cout<<"\nDelete 50\n";
    root = deleteNode(root, 50);
    cout<<"Inorder traversal of the modified tree \n";
    inorder(root);/*/


    /*
    insert(root, 80);*/

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: You shouldn't name your structs and variables same.

Answer (score 1):

When you are printing out the `key`, you can also print out the other information of each `node`. Here's a solution using `cout`:

```
void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        std::cout << root->key << " " << root->name << " " << root->num << "\n";
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried, however, the name does not display it, it only puts symbols and the number that is another integer throws me numbers that are not, any other idea?

Comment: You are not adding all the `node` information to your tree. You are only using the `key` part of the node. You need to update `newNode`, and `insert` to use all that information.

Comment: Could you help me tell me how I could do it? I have already tried, but I cannot read the whole line using the key.

Answer (score 0):

There were some main problems and some other problems. The main problems were that you didn't store and print all data. I did the following:

- Clean up includes
- Remove `using namespace std;`
- Rename struct `node` to `Node`
- Add a struct for `Person` next to the struct for `Node`
- Add a constructor for `Person` to `Node`
- Make `insert` a method
- Use smart pointers. One problem of dynamic memory allocation is that you have to clean up but you didn't

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Person {
  int key;
  std::string name;
  int num;
};

struct Node : Person {
  Node(const Person &person) : Person(person) {}
  std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
  void insert(const Person &person);
};

void Node::insert(const Person &person) {
  /* recur down the tree */
  if (key > person.key) {
    if (left)
        left->insert(person);
    else
        left = std::make_unique<Node>(person);
  } else if (key < person.key) {
    if (right)
        right->insert(person);
    else
        right = std::make_unique<Node>(person);
  }
}

std::vector<Person> persons;

void inorder(Node *root) {
  if (root) {
    // cout<<"\t";

    inorder(root->left.get());
    std::cout << '\t' << root->key << ' ' << root->name << ' ' << root->num << '\n';
    inorder(root->right.get());
  }
}

Node *minValueNode(Node *node) {
  Node *current = node;

  /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
  while (current && current->left) current = current->left.get();

  return current;
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
  std::ifstream fin("data.txt");
  if (!fin) {
    std::cout << "File not open\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::string line;
  const char delim = ',';

  while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    Person person;
    ss >> person.key;
    ss.ignore(10, delim);
    std::getline(ss, person.name, delim);
    ss >> person.num;
    if (ss) persons.push_back(person);
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << persons[i].key << std::setw(20)
              << persons[i].name << std::setw(15) << persons[i].num << '\n';
    if (!root) root = std::make_unique<Node>(persons[i]);
    else root->insert(persons[i]);
  }

  std::cout << "\n\nInorder:\n";
  //    cout<<node.name;

  inorder(root.get());

  /*/cout<<"\nDelete 50\n";
  root = deleteNode(root, 50);
  cout<<"Inorder traversal of the modified tree \n";
  inorder(root);/*/

  /*
  insert(root, 80);*/

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: hey how could i declare the search function?

Comment: `bool search(Node *root, intmax_t dato)`
`{`

   ` if(root){`
    `return false;`
   ` }`
    `else if(root->key==dato){`
        `return true;`
   ` }`
   `else if(dato<root->key){`
       `search(root->left.get(),dato);`
    `}`
    `else{`
        `return search(root->right.get(),dato);`
  ` }`

`}`

Comment: @Erick I would make it a member function

Comment: I managed to do it but only with the bool I would like that when putting the key it throws me the data of the person found, could you help me.

Comment: @Erick What do you mean with _throw_? Throw an exception?

Comment: What I want is a search function, where the Key is requested and shows the data of that variable, which would be the name and number of the data found, always using key as the key.

Comment: @Erick You could return `std::optional<Person>`

Comment: How could I do it? Any example you could give me is the last thing I lack.

Comment: @Erick `std::optional<Person> search(Node *root, intmax_t dato)` Return `{}` instead of `false` and `*root` instead of `true`

Comment: ´bool busqueda(Node *root, intmax_t dato) {
    if(root==NULL){
    return {};
    }
    else if(root->key==dato){
        return root;
    }
    else if(dato<root->key){
       return busqueda(root->left.get(),dato);
    }
    else{
        return busqueda(root->right.get(),dato);
    }
}´

Comment: The same thing happens to me validates if it exists or not, but when showing it it always shows me the first in the list and not the one that was found.

Comment: @Erick What is `busqueda`?

Comment: @Erick Why not `std::optional<Person> search(Node *root, intmax_t dato)`?

Comment: because  'optional' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type|

Comment: @Erick You have to include `optional`.

Comment: @Erick You don't know how to include header files? How is this possible? How did you write the code?

Comment: @Erick Experimental? What compiler do you use? `std::optional` is in C++17. It's already 3 years old.